# How to best show local time of an event?

Tags: javascript, date

I have an event that happens every day at 1AM UTC.  I am trying to find the easiest way to show the local time to the user:

```
document.getElementById('local').innerHTML=(new Date(3600000)).toLocaleTimeString();
```

works half the year.  But it does not take in to account day light savings time so right now in places that use day light savings it is off by an hour.  It is correct for those places that don't use day light savings time though.

Comment: "*…in places that use day light savings it is off by an hour*" In that case the implementation is broken or the system settings are wrong. The whole point of *toLocaleTimeString* is to represent the time in a "local" format, including the correct timezone offset of the host system. Note that 3600000 represents 1am on 1 Jan 1970 UTC, so daylight saving might not be being observed then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show an event that occurs at 1 am UTC in a locale aware format, you have to include the date portion as well. You can't just use `new Date(3600000)` as that is 1970-01-01 01:00:00 UTC, so you'll get the timezone offset for then (which might be different because of daylight saving or because the locale has changed its offset).

So if you want every 1 am UTC for the next 7 days, then:

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setUTCHours(1,0,0,0);
for (var i=7; i>0; i--) {
  console.log(d.toLocaleString());
  d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 1);
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out why my code wouldn't work and proper way to fix.  I kept the `.toLocaleTimeString()` from my original code so it just shows the time but now it shows daylight correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
const timeZoneValue = "Asia/Kolkata";
const localeStr = "en-US";

document.getElementById('local').innerHTML=(new Date().toLocaleString(localeStr , {timeZone: timeZoneValue}));
```

Comment: Why would "Asia/Kolkata" use "en-US"? The official language is Bengali (bn).

Comment: @RobG, "Asia/Kolkata" for setting up timezone and "en-US" is for localestring whatever locale you want to setup for Date

Answer (score 0):

```js
var oneam = new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(1,0,0,0));
console.log(oneam.toString())
```

will get today at 1am UTC, as a local time string.